# Volley NetworkImageView with spinner?

Tags: android, android-volley

so I want to provide some feedback to the user while I am loading a gridview of images. Below is my adapters UI. I have a very nasty way of doing my task, adding a spinner to each element of the gridview. When the NetworkImageView loads it hides the spinner..

However I ask myself, do I want to use or show this to anyone? No way, aside from being a hack, having 8+ spinners is terrible for performance.

I've been researching it... I see there is some copyNpaste a custom version of the NetworkImageViewer code that lets me put an observer, but that seems to be way intense / overkill.

I also tried putting a callback into the get / set image in the volley ImageLoader to turn off the spinners when the data is accessed. It half worked, but decided it was too ugly of a solution as well.

Aside from just doing it manually with the normal volley request and having to process the image manually and putting it on the volley success listener.. I'm stumped. Anyone know of a clean solution here? I'm guessing I have to do it manually..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/element_spacing"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/element_spacing">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/element_spacing"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/grid_adapter_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_adapter_networkimageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/element_spacing"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To counterpart me, I just did it manually, no network image view..

Comment: spinners seem to work with ImageView but not NetworkImageView unless you create your own custom one

Comment: This is a pretty old post. That is what I did if I recall. Used normal Volley to download it, and hit it with a graphic over it.